# Tagging Knowledge Articlees

Tags: knowledge

What is the best way to "tag" knowledge articles? By tagging I mean functionality similar to that of StackExchange in that I can assign none, one or more labels/tags to an article.

1. Is this achievable?
2. Would it be useful even if I can hack it i.e. could I use this in search?

Comment: We use data categories to accomplish this. http://na2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/category_whatis.htm

Comment: I tried them out, can you assign several to an article? Can you query on them?

Comment: You can definitely assign several to an article, not sure about querying on them.

Comment: It turns out that you can query them. If I have an Knowledge Article type called "Q&A" then I can query articles and their associated Data Category like so: `SELECT CreatedById,CreatedDate,DataCategoryGroupName,DataCategoryName,Id,IsDeleted,ParentId,SystemModstamp FROM Q_A__DataCategorySelection`

Answer (score 4):

I have a good news, Topics on Article are GA with Spring'14 release. See the "Assign Topics to Articles" section of the release notes: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Way long past the time that this question was asked, and in the spirit better late than never answered I offer... Topics are coming to knowledge articles in pilot in the Winter '14 release.

https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter14_release_notes.pdf